# multiple consumers in a single queue in ActiveMQ

Tags: c#, activemq-classic

> I have tried single consumer and producer it works fine , as well as
>   the multiple consumers with sinlge producer . But what i really want
>   to know ,  is it really possible to have multiple consumers in a
>   single queue in ActiveMQ.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for broadcasting http://activemq.apache.org/broadcasting.html

Comment: not exactly for braodcasting , for that i can use topic . But in my case I was just trying , if is it possible to queue it up in a single queue from multiple consumer, rather than having a different queue for every consumer.

Comment: it is possible to have multiple consumers in a single queue in ActiveMQ. take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470534/multithreaded-jms-client-activemq/42472281#42472281

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? What problem did you get using multiple consumers ?